# Postgres query fails without schema

Tags: postgresql

THis doesn't work, resulting in `ERROR: relation "user" does not exist`

```
select * from "user"
```

This one does

```
select * from "dbo"."user"
```

Comment: That suggests your `search_path` does not include the `dbo` schema. What's the output of `SHOW search_path;` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger it shows `""$user",public"`

Comment: ... and are you connected as user `dbo`?

Comment: @CraigRinger as user `postgres`

Comment: So it's not working because it's not on the `search_path`. So you have to schema-qualify it. That's the point of having schemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables that aren't schema-qualified are searched for on the `search_path`. This doesn't search every schema. By default it only searches:

- `pg_catalog` (implicitly always first, not listed on `search_path`)
- `pg_temp` tablespaces (implicit, not listed on `search_path`)
- A schema named after the current user, listed as `$user` in `search_path`
- The `public` schema

If you want PostgreSQL to look elsewhere you have to modify the `search_path` to tell it so, or fully schema-qualify the name.

See [the PostgreSQL manual on `search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-SEARCH-PATH).

Also, note that unlike some databases the name `dbo` has no particular significance in PostgreSQL. It's just another name.

Comment: I notice that if a view uses a table whose schema is not on the search path (say, removed after creating the view), Postgres actually returns data.
When you try to run the select itself outside that view, the query fails. That happens after removing a schema from the search path..
Re-adding the schema to the view gets lost after creating the view. Annoying.

Comment: @RTD That's because the view's `search_path` is resolved at view creation time and "baked in" to the view. It's good practice to explicitly qualify your references in views and functions, rather than relying on the search path.

Comment: I remember I explicitly hardcoded the schema name in the view when creating it. After saving, Postgres modified the view in its own way, which removed the schema name from the view definition since it was in the `search_path`. However, after removing the schema from the search path, it looked like the view wasn't refactored... I unfortunately don't have time to test this hypothesis, thank you for the reply.